# com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.defineClass is null runtime error

Tags: gradle, java-17

After upgrading to JDK17 and Gradle to 7.3.2, I get the following runtime exception:

```
"errorType":"java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"
"errorMessage":"java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"
"cause":{3 items
"errorType":"java.lang.NullPointerException"
"errorMessage":"Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object[])" because "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.defineClass" is null"
"stackTrace":[40 items
0:"com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:311)"
1:"com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:97)"
2:"com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:87)"
3:"com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:179)"
4:"com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:285)"
5:"com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:94)"
6:"java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)"
7:"java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)"
8:"java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)"
9:"java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Unknown Source)"
10:"java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)"
11:"com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)"
12:"com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)"
13:"com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:514)"
14:"com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:331)"
15:"com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)"
16:"com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1156)"
17:"com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:165)"
18:"java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"
19:"java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)"
20:"java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)"
21:"java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"
22:"javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:251)"
23:"javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:240)"
24:"javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)"
25:"javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)"
26:"javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:632)"
27:"org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:122)"
28:"org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)"
29:"org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)"
30:"org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)"
```

I searched and added
implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '3.0.2'
to the build.gradle. But still have the same issue.
This was working with JDK 11.
Any idea what is causing this ?